# UIRefreshControl of tableView covers first cell when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have set up a refreshControl on my tableView like this:

```
func setupRefreshControl() {
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pullToRefreshDevicesTV), for: .valueChanged)
        devicesTableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }
```

Here are some pictures for reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwGtD.jpg

The Activity Indicator overlaps with the first cell when the user scrolls the TableView. (Picture 1 & 2)

When I scroll down the tableView till the point, where it is at it's 'usual' state, without the refreshControl loading, the indicator hides. (Picture 3)

I would like the refreshControl to be hidden always when it collides with the first cell.

I have already tried adding the refreshControl on the first index of the tableView and I can't push it to the background, because my cells are transparent.

Comment: Does the table view itself have a background color? If not, try setting it to white (or whatever else suits you best).

Comment: The tableview background needs to be .clear

Comment: Well, then you won't be able to solve it, as this is the expected behavior.

Comment: I can not imagine that, are you sure? Where is it written in the documentation, and why is it so ugly like that?

Comment: @AliPacman not everything is documented. The reason places Stack exist. Take his advice, he’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in my comment, you *have to* set a background color for your `UITableView` itself.
Otherwise, the activity indicator will be visible below the table view - which makes sense because it's behind the table view, but the table view is transparent, so it's expected to see the activity indicator view.

There may be 3rd-party solutions for this where a custom activity indicator is implemented, but for the native one, there's no other solution.